# How can I get a report of all work items added to an iteration after a given date?

Tags: tfs

I need to produce a report, similar to the Unplanned Work report included with the MS Agile Process Template, but which lists me all work items which were added to an iteration *after* a given date.

The work item may have already been created before that date, so I can't used the created date.

Can anyone give any guidance on how I can go about this? If I can achieve it in Excel then that would be perfect...

Thanks.

Comment: Do you also have an SQL analysis server running as part of your TFS deployment?

Comment: Yep- I did think it likely that this information will be available from there, I'm just not too sure of how I go about extracting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, took some work. Interesting enough though to put some effort in it ...

First screenshot is a Pivot table connected to the Analysis Cube. The most left colum shows the ID of a workitem. The second column shows the ChangeDate. In the row header I have included every iteration that I am interested in. What you see happening in the Excel sheet is items moving from one sprint to the other. For example, workitem 27 was created for iteration 1 at 14-3-2011. On 13-4-2011 it was moved to iteration 2. On 12-5-2011 it was moved to iteration 3. etc.

[image]

If I narrow down the filter to a specific iteration I actually see items entering the iteration and leaving the iteration. If I also change the ChangeDate filter, I can focus on items entering after a specific date, as you requested. Again, you can see item 27 enter iteration 2 at 13-4 and leave at 12-5. You can juggle around with the columns to get the view you want.

[image]

Finally, the options I used to get this view from TFS.

[image]

Hope this exceeds your expectations :-)